# Dynamically/programmatically add Arearegistrations in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anybody know how to add AreaRegistrations dynamically/programmatically?

I want to be able to write some logic for selecting AreaRegistrations.

Thx

Comment: Kenny, you can write some C# code when you have the TableRoute in the global.asax, but, take care with this.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems broader than what you're asking but it does deal with an approach to adding AreaRegistrations dynamically.

[Dynamically extending features of an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023748/dynamically-extending-features-of-an-application)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good example but no exactly what i'm looking for.