# Dynamic DB contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

My application has an underlying model and I use an Entity Framework DbContext for data access. In addition to the base application there are dynamically loaded modules, each represented by an assembly and loaded at runtime by the main application (all modules to load are configured in a configuration file). Modules can further depend on each other, e.g. ModC requires ModA and ModB to be loaded.

Modules provide additional views and services to the base application (i.e. extend the base application). Most of the time they add additional use cases to the base application.

Actual question regarding DbContext:
Modules extend the number of tables in the database or extend existing tables (by inheriting from base model classes).

a) Is there a way to provide a unified DbContext to a moduel without re-writing all DbSet<...>s in their DbContext? Inheritance from the base application's DbContext doesn't work as modules can depend on multiple other modules and multi-inheritance is not supported in C#.

b) How to run Entity Framework database migration correctly to incooperate all the migration scripts from the loaded modules correctly? More precisely: Modules are allowed to only add/extend the existing DB structure and therefore migration should happen the first time a module has been loaded, changes should not be removed once the module is unloaded, however, if the module is updated, the DB should be migrated the next time the module is loaded.

Hope there is any pattern or idea to implement such a scenario in C# / Entity Framework.

EDIT: On the view side it is comparable easy to implement with MVC's pluggable areas:
[Dynamically extending features of an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023748/dynamically-extending-features-of-an-application)
My hope is that there is something similar for the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess that if you use a dbContext that has more tables, for example, the business logic is different in each case. So perhaps you can do the following:

1.- Define an interface that has the CRUD operations and other methods that you need to work with the database.

2.- Implement a repository that implements this interface. You can have many repositories, so each one of the use a diffrent module.

3.- In you main application, you use the interface, that is instantiated with the repository you need in each case. So you call the methods of the interface, in the main application always has the same code. Only  to need is to know when to use a repository or other. This can be done with reflection or a class that is used as factory that decide which repository to use.